# Is this proof that an infinite sigma algebra is uncountable valid?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I was thinking about the proof I've seen of the statement "an infinite sigma algebra has at least the cardinality of the continuum" and an alternative popped into my head.

Since we're only concerned with cardinality, we count another set and show our sigma algebra is at least that large.

Since every infinite sigma algebra has an countable sequence of disjoint sets, that sequence can be paired bijectively with the rationals, which are also countable (and the smallest size of infinity possible).

By "converting" the countable union of rationals to addition, we generate every real number in the following way (and thus get a surjection, showing our sequence generates a sigma algebra at least as large as the reals, and proving the statement).

Write out $x \in \mathbb{R}$ as its expanded formal power series $\sum_{i=-\infty}^{\infty}a_i*10^i$, where the $a_i$ are in $[0..9]$. Then we can uniquely write each real as a countable sequence of rationals.

Example: $\pi$ would be mapped to by $(3 * 10 ^1, 1 * 10^{-1}, 4*10^{-2},..)$.

If we consider the (countable) union of the set of rationals used to do that for each $x$, we get a set in the sigma algebra generated by our sequence, and it covers the reals. The statement follows.

Does this work?

Answer (score 6):

Your principles are okay, but the proof can be formulated more concisely.

If $\mathcal A$ denotes a $\sigma$-algebra and $\{A_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ is a collection of non-empty disjoint elements of $\mathcal A$ then the map $\wp(\mathbb N)\to\mathcal A$ prescribed by $S\mapsto\bigcup_{n\in S}A_n$ is an *injection*.

So the uncountability of $\wp(\mathbb N)$ implies the uncountability of $\mathcal A$.

Comment: @MartinArgerami The $A_n$ are demanded to be non-empty and *disjoint* (so stronger than distinct).

Comment: My bad. I was looking for versions of the proof that countable $\sigma$-algebras don't exist. The non-trivial part of the proof is the existence of the sequence, which I didn't notice was omitted in OP.